# How to refresh the current time in Extjs

Tags: date, extjs, time

I created a window where is a form with some fields, among all of them there is a field which is showing the current time. I set it like this:

```
{
    xtype: 'timefield',
    x: 330,
    y: 25,
    labelWidth: 80,
    width: 320,
    readOnly: true,
    format: 'H:i:s',
    itemId: 'time',
    fieldLabel: 'Time',
    value: new Date(),
    name: 'time',
},
```

the output is the current time like this: **`17:52:16`**

Everything is fine so far. The problem come along when I open the window more than once. The first time I open the window the current time shows just fine but once I close the window and try to open it again the time shown is the one that it was shown the first time I opened the window.

I mean, let's say that I opened the window and the time was `15:51:23` then I close the window and a hour later I open that window again the time that shows me is `15:51:23` and not `16:51:23` which is the time that must be showing it. The time is no updating.

How can I refresh the time every time I open the window ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can listen on `show` event in window object.

> Fires after the component is shown when calling the show method.

You can attach listener as below:

```
listeners: {
    show: function (w, a,b) {
        w.down('#time').setValue(new Date());
    }
}
```

Take a look on example on fiddle : https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2u5o